# Why is my language bundle path returning nil in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, localization

So I have an extension for my string. I use simplified chinese and traditional chinese in my project. I was trying to manually switch language for my strings, but my

```
Bundle(path: URL(fileURLWithPath: bundlePath ?? "").deletingLastPathComponent().absoluteString)
```

is always returning `nil`. I have my localized strings in the Xcode project. Can anyone help?

```
 extension String {
    var localized: String {

        //zh-Hans.lproj
        let lang = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "i18n_language")
        let bundlePath: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Localizable", ofType: "strings", inDirectory: nil, forLocalization: "zh-Hans")
        print("bundlePath = \(String(describing: bundlePath!))")
        // here i get path as bundlePath = /var/containers/Bundle/Application/C3xx3D-BxxC-4Dx3-xx8D-156xxxxxxx3D/xxxx.app/zh-Hans.lproj/Localizable.strings
        let langBundle = Bundle(path: URL(fileURLWithPath: bundlePath ?? "").deletingLastPathComponent().absoluteString)
        print("langBundle = \(langBundle)") // getting nil

        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: langBundle!, value: "", comment: "")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `Bundle.main.url` ?

Comment: how will i set localisation with bundle.main.url?